# SQL stored procedure works but with errors

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I have table with 3 primary keys : `CODE_TARIF, UNITE`, and `MODE_LIV`.

I write a stored procedure to copy and paste but with different `MODE_LIV`.

ex: if I already have 2 rows in table `T_TARIF` with `MODE_LIV = 2,` when I run this stored procedure with input `MODE_LIV =3`, I will have 4 rows .

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Copy_Tarif]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @MODE_LIV int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CODE_TARIF varchar(15)
    DECLARE @ZONE int
    DECLARE @UNITE int
    DECLARE @LIBELLE varchar(30)

    DECLARE @TR_DEB int
    DECLARE @TR_FIN int
    DECLARE @MONTANT decimal(18,2)


    DECLARE tarif_cursor CURSOR FOR     
    SELECT CODE_TARIF, ZONE, UNITE, LIBELLE, TR_DEBUT, TR_FIN, MONTANT
    FROM T_TARIF

    OPEN tarif_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM tarif_cursor 
    INTO  @CODE_TARIF, @ZONE, @UNITE, @LIBELLE,  @TR_DEB, @TR_FIN, @MONTANT;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [T_TARIF]
           ([CODE_TARIF]
           ,[ZONE]
           ,[UNITE] 
           ,[MODE_LIV]         
           ,[LIBELLE]
           ,[TR_DEBUT]
           ,[TR_FIN]
           ,[MONTANT]

           )
     VALUES
           (@CODE_TARIF
           ,@ZONE
           ,@UNITE   
           ,@MODE_LIV       
           ,@LIBELLE
           ,@TR_DEB
           ,@TR_FIN
           ,@MONTANT

           )

        FETCH NEXT FROM tarif_cursor
        INTO  @CODE_TARIF, @ZONE, @UNITE, @LIBELLE,  @TR_DEB, @TR_FIN, @MONTANT;



    END
END
```

It works, but gives an error see Video : [Strange Stored Procedure](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stevchen99/6266223618/)

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: Please describe the error. I don't particularly want to watch a video to work out what your question is asking!

Comment: Thanks you for responding, it inserted the data but return error vialotion primary key.

Comment: Your cursor SELECT's result set might include rows where `MODE_LIV` is already equal to the target value of `@MODE_LIV`. Or there might be rows with identical `CODE_TARIF` & `UNITE` but different `MODE_LIV`. So my point is, you should add some filtering to the cursor SELECT (or, better still, to the SELECT part of the INSERT statement as suggested by [@gbn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848261/sql-stored-procedure-works-but-with-errors/7848318#7848318))

Answer (score 1):

*Guessing*...

You are using ISO cursor syntax. This defaults to not INSENSITIVE . Which means as you insert rows then when you FETCH you get rows you have just inserted etc etc.

From DECLARE CURSOR

> DECLARE cursor_name [ INSENSITIVE ] [ SCROLL ] CURSOR
>
> Defines a cursor that makes a temporary copy of the data to be used by the cursor. All requests to the cursor are answered from this temporary table in tempdb; therefore, modifications made to base tables are not reflected in the data returned by fetches made to this cursor, and this cursor does not allow modifications. **When ISO syntax is used, if INSENSITIVE is omitted, committed deletes and updates made to the underlying tables (by any user) are reflected in subsequent fetches.**

In any event, all you need is this: No need to loop

```
 INSERT INTO [T_TARIF]
       ([CODE_TARIF]
       ,[ZONE]
       ,[UNITE] 
       ,[MODE_LIV]         
       ,[LIBELLE]
       ,[TR_DEBUT]
       ,[TR_FIN]
       ,[MONTANT])
 SELECT 
       [CODE_TARIF]
       ,[ZONE]
       ,[UNITE] 
       ,@MODE_LIV       
       ,[LIBELLE]
       ,[TR_DEBUT]
       ,[TR_FIN]
       ,[MONTANT]
 FROM
      [T_TARIF]
```

Comment: @user609511: you don't need a loop: SQL is designed to work with more that one row

Comment: Thanks you for responding, i try with `DECLARE tarif_cursor INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR` but still error. i need loop because i inserted more than 1 row. i don't know how ? i must select * from table and then where i put this to tmporary variable ?

Comment: i try with no loop -> i got only 1 row inserted.

Comment: i follow your answer but still got : `Violation de la contrainte PRIMARY KEY 'PK_T_TARIF' `

Comment: @user609511: of course. It means that the combination of CODE_TARIF, UNITE, and MODE_LIV already exists